# Help understanding Archimedes method for finding the area of a circle

Tags: geometry

I'm struggling to understand the method described on this page

http://www.ugrad.math.ubc.ca/coursedoc/math101/notes/integration/archimedes.html

specifically step 1, I can't replicate how they have got from 2r being the diameter to a value of sqrt 2r for the length of sides AB and BC.

Could someone have a look at the question and demonstrate the working to arrive at the above answer?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Draw the other diagonal of the square and apply the Pythagorean Theorem to the so-formed right triangles.

Comment: Thank you that has helped me figure it out

Comment: It is annoying that the linked file attribute the result to Archimedes, since it is much older, and is traditionally attributed to Eudoxus.